# ffmpeg performance with hundreds of cuts (atrim)

Tags: python, audio, ffmpeg

I have audio files (think ~2h) where I want to cut out a lot of  pieces out of it (500+) and a ffmpeg command like this one:

```
['ffmpeg', '-i', 'pipe:', '-filter_complex', 
'[0]atrim=end=30.69:start=0.0[s0];
 [0]atrim=end=34.31:start=31.18[s1];
 [0]atrim=end=38.65:start=34.43[s2]; 
 (... hundreds more)
 [s37][s38][s39][s40][s41]concat=a=1:n=42:v=0[s42]', '-map', '[s42]']
```

Stream mapping built with ffmpeg-python:

```
  Stream #0:0 (mp3float) -> atrim
  (... hundreds more)
  Stream #0:0 (mp3float) -> atrim
  concat -> Stream #0:0 (libmp3lame)
```

Now this works as expected but it takes locally something like 10mins for the files I have and when I deploy it to some server in the cloud it takes something like an hour. It definitely depends on the machine obviously and I definitely scale there the speed but I'd also like to know if there's a way to speed up the processing with ffmpeg itself.

Thanks for any pointers!

Comment: Show the complete log from `ffmpeg -i input.foo`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Why do you feed your files to `ffmpeg` via a pipe? If you provide the input by path, `ffmpeg` will be enabled to seek within the file and quickly skip over the fragments that must be dropped, whereas with pipe input it has no choice but scan the entire input sequentially.

Besides, when using file inputs, you can take advantage of the [`concat` demuxer](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Concatenate#demuxer) with stream copy, saving significantly on decoding and re-encoding.

For your example the input to the concat demuxer should be something like below (note that the same file name is used for different fragments):

**cut.ffconcat**

```
ffconcat version 1.0

file input.mp3
inpoint 0.0
outpoint 30.69

file input.mp3
inpoint 31.18
outpoint 34.31

...
```

`ffmpeg` command line:

```
ffmpeg -i cut.ffconcat -codec copy cut.mp3
```

In my experiment (250 5-second segments cut from a 42 minute long mp3 file) the runtime difference was more than 3x: the concat demuxer + stream copy approach took 36 seconds vs 110 seconds of your `atrim` + `concat` filters solution.

Note, however, that the cutting accuracy may be worse when utilizing the concat demuxer approach (I suspect that it will cut only at the audio frame boundaries).

Comment: Thanks for the inputs! I actually had it with the input path instead of the pipe but when executing the command (at least seemed) to be stuck. Will have to try again in that case. 

That's a good hint with the concat demuxer. When I saw that possibility to speed it up I was skeptical that it's a good idea to generate hundreds of files and concat them together. Another reason though was b/c I also wanted to use other filters in combination with the trim (fading). I guess this wouldn't work then anymore. But that's out of scope of the initial question. Will try and circle back!

Comment: @drakon *I was skeptical that it's a good idea to generate hundreds of files and concat them together* You don't have to generate a separate file for each fragment. I updated the answer with an example.

Comment: Thanks Leon for the  updated answer! I actually tried it now and it is was faster but there are now artefacts in the concatenated audio. Not sure if it's related to this error/warning/info that ffmpg gives now: "Application provided invalid, non monotonically increasing dts to muxer in stream 0: 27855 >= 27225" or it's because the other filters are removed with this method. But I guess my initial question is answered.